# How to declare a module in TypeScript with an object as default export

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-declaration

In a TypeScript project, I would like to use a third-party library that does not provide type definitions. So I need to come up with my own module declaration. What the module basically exports looks like this:

```
const foo = {
  bar () {
    return 23;
  }
};

module.exports = foo;
```

So, the question now is how to come up with the module declaration. First of all, it's obvious that the module uses a `default` export, not a named one. This default export is an object, which has methods. So I tried this:

```
declare module 'foo' {
  export default {
    bar(): number;
  };
}
```

However, the TypeScript compiler complains that:

> The expression of an export statement must be an identifier or a qualified name in an ambient context.

What does this mean? Using `bar`, I have used an identifier, haven't I? And what does "qualified name in an ambient context" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using bar, I have used an identifier, haven't I?

The error is talking about the object of the export clause. While you have used `bar` as an identifier, specifically as a method name, you are not exporting that identifier, you are exporting an object literal contains it.

In

```
declare module 'foo' {
  export default {bar(): number};
}
```

the identifier `bar` refers to a method of the exported value not the exported value itself.

To correct this, write

```
declare module 'foo' {
  const foo: {bar(): number};
  export default foo;
}
```

A qualified name is one which is referred to by qualifying its name with its enclosing scope as in `a.b`

```
declare module 'foo' {
  namespace ns {
    const foo: {bar(): number};
  }
  export default ns.foo; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I didn't really get this sentence: "[…] refers to a method of the exported value not the exported value itself.", could you maybe explain a little bit more on this?

Comment: I tried to elaborate a bit. Basically `bar` is the method name but you are exporting `default {bar}` not `default bar`. Perhaps you are confused between `export {name}` (export list containing name) and `export default name` which equivalent to `export {name as default
}`